# R: Conditional row sum for data frame based on conditions in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, conditional-statements

I have a data frame `dfcompanies` in which about 6000 companies are listed with their identification code `indentifier`, their industry `industry` and their score `(NA, 0, or 1)` in 132 different categories e.g. `category1-4`:

```
> dfcompanies

    identifier  industry            category1   category2   category3   category4

1   MBWS.PA     Alcoholic Beverages 1           0           1           1
2   KAER.VI     Commercial Banks    0           1           0           1
3   TIRO.VI     Commercial Banks    1           NA          1           0
4   EVNV.VI     Power Generation    0           1           1           1
5   MANV.VI     Processed Foods     NA          0           NA          NA
6   LENV.VI     Chemical            1           NA          1           1
```

I also have a second data frame, `dfmatcategories` which defines for all the industries present in `industry`; listed in the column `industrymat`; their material categories in `categorymat` and describes the category `type` `(strength, or concern)` in the third column:

```
> dfmatcategories

    industrymat         categorymat type

1   Alcoholic Beverages category1   concern
2   Alcoholic Beverages category2   strength
3   Alcoholic Beverages category3   strength
4   Insurance           category100 strength
5   Insurance           category99  strength
6   Chemical            category1   concern
```

Ideally, I would like to get for each company in `dfcompanies` the sum of the points received in the material categories as defined in `categorymat` that have the `type` `strength` in a new column `sum_mat` added to `dfcompanies`.

```
> dfcompanies

    identifier  industry            category1   category2   category3   category4   sum_mat

1   MBWS.PA     Alcoholic Beverages 1           0           1           1           1
2   KAER.VI     Commercial Banks    0           1           0           1           5
3   TIRO.VI     Commercial Banks    1           NA          1           0           3
4   EVNV.VI     Power Generation    0           1           1           1           4
5   MANV.VI     Processed Foods     NA          0           NA          NA          1
6   LENV.VI     Chemical            1           NA          1           1           0
```

**Example:**

In `dfcompanies` the company with the `indentifier` `MBWS.PA` belongs to the `industry` `Alcoholic Beverages` and received a scores of: `1` in `category1`, `0` in `category2`, `1` in `category3`,  and also `1` in `category4`.

In `dfmatcategories` under `industrymat` for `Alcoholic Beverages`
rows `1-3` in column `categorymat` list only `category1`, `category2`, and `category3` as material categories.

However, only `category2`, and `category3` are of the `type` `strength`.

Hence for `MBWS.PA` `sum_mat => 1`  `=` `0`(score `category2`) `+`  `1` (score `category3`).

Unfortunately, I am new to R and utterly clueless about how to approach this problem.

Can someone please help me?

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: I'm not able to understand how you calculate `sum_mat`, how you get the values `1,5,3` and so on. Are those calculated values for your original data frame or the example given here?

Comment: To illustrate I added the calculation of sum_mat for MBWS.PA. The given data is only for illustration, other values than sum_mat for MBWS.PA can not be calculated by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution based in the tidyverse does the trick by pivoting your data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfcompanies %>%
  full_join(dfmatcategories, by = c('industry' = 'industrymat')) %>%
  filter(!identifier %in% NA) %>%
  pivot_longer(category1:category4) %>%
  mutate(sum_mat = if_else(categorymat == name & 
                           type =='strength' &
                           value == 1, 1, 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(identifier) %>%
  mutate(sum_mat = sum(sum_mat)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(colnames(dfcompanies), sum_mat)

# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#   identifier industry            category1 category2 category3 category4 sum_mat
#   <chr>      <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 EVNV.VI    Power Generation            0        NA        NA        NA      NA
# 2 KAER.VI    Commercial Banks            0        NA         0        NA      NA
# 3 LENV.VI    Chemical                    1        NA         1         1       0
# 4 MANV.VI    Processed Foods            NA        NA        NA        NA      NA
# 5 MBWS.PA    Alcoholic Beverages         1         1         1         1       2
# 6 TIRO.VI    Commercial Banks            1        NA         1        NA      NA
```

**Data**

```
dfcompanies <- structure(list(identifier = c("MBWS.PA", "KAER.VI", "TIRO.VI", 
"EVNV.VI", "MANV.VI", "LENV.VI"), industry = c("Alcoholic Beverages", 
"Commercial Banks", "Commercial Banks", "Power Generation", "Processed Foods", 
"Chemical"), category1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, NA, 1), category2 = c(1, 
1, NA, 1, 0, NA), category3 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, NA, 1), category4 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, NA, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

dfmatcategories <- structure(list(industrymat = c("Alcoholic Beverages", "Alcoholic Beverages", 
"Alcoholic Beverages", "Insurance", "Insurance", "Chemical"), 
    categorymat = c("category1", "category2", "category3", "category100", 
    "category99", "category1"), type = c("concern", "strength", 
    "strength", "strength", "strength", "concern")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank You! Your solution gets me about 90% of the way there. Unfortunately, I have not covered the complete workflow in my example. I run into issues as soon as a company in `dfcompanies` receives a score of `0, or NA` in any of the `category1-4` that is defined as material for its `industry` under `industrymat` and of `type` `strength`. The company then gets a `1` to its `sum_mat` even though its score is `0, or NA`.

Comment: You are very welcome @NeuThomas95. I have edited my answer. I hope it works for you now.

Comment: Thank you again @rjen ! I have made a small addition to your code:`mutate(sum_mat = sum(sum_mat, na.rm = TRUE))` now `NA` values at material `categories1-4`are considered as `0` for `sum`. I applied the new code to my original data and everything works smoothly!